# Stripe Redirect Url

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to connect users to my Stripe account.
          https://stripe.com/docs/apps/getting-started
I tried setting the redirect url to localhost. I then get an error than safari can't open the page "" because safari can't connect to the server "". Does anyone know what I should set the redirect url to?

Comment: Check your server settings and make sure that **a)** your server is up and running, and **b)** that it's listening on the correct port. What kind of server are you running? Apache?

Comment: Yes I'm running Apache. It's Linode.

Comment: Should I be redirecting them elsewhere? To another page on my website? Will it work to redirect them to localhost?

Comment: If you redirect "them" to localhost, it will attempt to access the client's local server, which I assume is not the behavior you want. If you want to send them to an absolute URL, you need to define a global variable (or a `CONSTANT` - this is the preferred way) that is set to whatever the site root is. So if you have two environments, (development and production) you will have to set up some logic that says `if (development) { define('SITEROOT', "http://localhost/"); } else { define('SITEROOT', /*site root URL*/); }`.

Comment: I know it's a year later but i'm able to set my redirect url to `http://localhost/foobar` and Stripe sends it there.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the redirect url to localhost, the server will try to redirect to it's localhost.
Set the redirect url with a public domain or ip.